# Is the second "they" facultative in expressions like "What they do is they..."?

Tags: phrase-choice

In the internet  I have found a lot of sentences like "Basically what they do is give you a free gift", see, in particular,
"All they do is (to) get groceries"  [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/114879/all-they-do-is-get-getting-groceries). I'm in doubt, however - wouldn't they sound better with "they": "Basically what they do is *they* give you a free gift"? Or this depends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. The construction without "they" is idiomatic, and what you'll usually see in writing, but sometimes you might hear "they" or another pronoun interjected in there. Beware, though - grammatically it's a different construction, and it might subtly change the meaning of the sentence.

"All he does is go to the store" - it's a simple, idiomatic sentence, meaning that the person you're describing doesn't do anything *in general* but go to the store. It describes a habit, or lifestyle.

"All he does is, he goes to the store" - it's much less idiomatic,and it introduces a new sentence halfway through. Grammatically, it's as if you started to speak and backtracked to say something else - and since your new sentence is just "he goes to the store", it might also mean (and without context I'd read it that way) that you're describing a single event in which you've seen the person go to the store and haven't seen them do anything else.

In your example the meaning is more or less the same, since it's evident from the context and the use of generic "you" that "they give you a free gift" by itself means they always give you a gift. But if the sentence was "they give *me* free gifts", it could be read two ways:

"Basically what they do is give me free gifts" - in general, as far as you're concerned, the company gives you free gifts on a regular basis. They might not have given you any yet, but as a rule that's what they do.

"Basically what they do is, they give me free gifts" - might mean the same as above, but might also be describing a single or reoccurring event in which you've received gifts from them.